# Error message "loading hook" for content search

Tags: configuration, logging, error-handling

I have configured two Sitecore servers (CM and CD) using Sitecore 8.2.7. On CD server, Sitecore page is properly shown on the browser but there is a error message shown in the log folder as shown below.

```
4668 19:37:07 ERROR Error loading hook: <hook type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Hooks.Initializer, Sitecore.ContentSearch" patch:source="Sitecore.ContentSearch.config" xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" />
```

We are using Azure Search for content searching but not sure how this is causing error.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Is there a stack trace that goes with the error?